# Some WebKit2GTK WebContext functions missing from opensuse webkit2gtk4-devel c-headers

Tags: c, webkit, opensuse, webkitgtk, webcontext

My installed version `webkit2gtk4-devel` 2.40.0 doesn't have all the functions, which are stated from the WebKitGTK documentation found [here](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/2.40.0/index.html).
The currently missing functions, which I have come across are (there are probably more):

- `webkit_web_context_new_ephemeral`
- `webkit_web_context_new_with_website_data_manager`
- `webkit_web_context_set_sandbox_enabled`

Also, I cannot create the objects with `g_object_new`, as the property `website-data-manager` for web context also for some reason doesn't exist.

I looked around for the functions in `/usr/include/webkitgtk-6.0/webkit/WebKitWebContext.h` and they do indeed seem to be missing. But if I look at `/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.1/....`, the functions are all there (that directory comes from my own compiled version of HEAD).

I have tried both of these repos:

- [Factory](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/openSUSE%3AFactory/webkit2gtk3%3Agtk4)
- [GNOME:Next](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/GNOME%3ANext/webkit2gtk3%3Agtk4)

I am thinking, that maybe the build service somehow doesn't compile it correctly, but I'm not sure.
Also, I haven't posted the question on WebKitGTK forums, as I can't sign up for it for some reason and it doesn't seem very active.

Comment: *I haven't posted the question on webkitgtk forums* you probably should post a bug report to the opensuse trackers, it's the opensuse devs who decided how to patch the code they ship.

Answer (score 1):

The api differs from gtk3 to gtk4.
WebKit Bugzilla offers a lot of clarification:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=222366

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=250835

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=220117

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).